# Using PrintWriter and DataOutputStream to write in same file in java

Tags: java, file

I have to write both `PrintWriter` and `DataOutputStream` to print data onto my file. But `PrintWriter` is getting printed earlier than `DataOutputStream` though it comes after `DataOutputStream` in code.

Part of code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class file {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataOutputStream dos=null;
        PrintWriter pw=null;
        try {
            File f=new File("file.txt");
            dos=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
            pw=new PrintWriter(f);
            Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);

            for(int i=0;i<=4;i++) {
                int h=b.nextInt();
                b.nextLine();
                dos.writeInt(h);
                String s=b.nextLine();
                int l=s.length();
                dos.writeBytes(s);
                pw.println();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(dos!=null)
                try {
                    dos.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            pw.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

new line from pw is getting printed first and then data from `dos.write();` how to avoid this?? and make it get in order?

Comment: Why not use `dos.write('\n');` and get rid of the PrintWriter ?

Comment: "I have to write both `PrintWriter` and `DataOutputStream` to print data onto my file." No you don't, because you can't mix `Writers` and `OutputStreams` on the same file, or text and binary, or buffered and unbuffered output either. There is a design problem here.

Comment: dos.write('\n') doesnot print any thing in text file ..any suggestions?

Comment: @user3527099 Rubbish. It write a newline. ASCII 10 or 0xA. `\n`. You have not addressed my comment.

Comment: @EJP you are right about not mixing both but I realized printing new line is not useful in binary file so I try to avoid using dos and write only reader

Comment: You have it exactly back to front. You should be using *only* `DataOutputStream` and getting rid of the `Writer`. Your stament that '`dos.write('\n')` does not write anything' remains incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mix a `Writer` and an `OutputStream` as they are used for different purpose, indeed a `Writer` is used to generate a text file (readable by a human being) and an `OutputStream` is used to generate a binary file (not readable by a human being), use only one of them according to your requirements.

Assuming that you decide to use only the `DataOutputStream` simply replace `pw.println()` with something like `dos.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))` to write the line separator into your file with your `OutputStream`. However please note that in a binary file adding a line separator doesn't really make sense since the file is not meant to be read by a human being.